# How to embed a gem into a RubyCocoa app?

Tags: ruby, cocoa, rubygems

I'd like to embed 2 gems into my RubyCocoa app, so the user doesn't have to install them on the console on him-/herself. But I can't find any information on about how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RubyCocoa includes a tool called standaloneify.rb that will include dependencies in your application bundle. Find it at `[path to RubyCocoa.framework]/Versions/A/MacOS/Tools/standaloneify.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not to familiar with how RubyCocoa deals with things, but I'd imagine you could use `gem unpack` to extract the gem source to some directory in your project root and then reference the library from there.